# Nextjs: render content based on sidebar choice

Tags: reactjs, next.js, polaris

I have started playing a bit with Shopify Polaris, in particular, the [Frame](https://codesandbox.io/s/pkhq8?module=App.js) layout:

https://polaris.shopify.com/components/structure/frame

What is not clear to me is that in the example provided by Shopify the sidebar, when an item is clicked, always toggles the `toggleIsLoading` method, and then it eventually always renders the `actualPageMarkup` component.

However, I would like to have a sidebar menu containing n different items. For each of them, I would like to render a particular component associated with the selection. How can I achieve this?

Ideally, I would like to always display the sidebar and the header, no matter what the component is.

I understand this question is not strictly related to Shopify Polaris or Next.js, however, I consider myself a newbie in both React and Next.js.